# Perform key translation in a major mode

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

`key-translation-map` allows you to globally translate keys.

For example:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<f11>") (kbd "<f12>"))
```

But what if I want to restrict the remapping to a particular major mode?

In my case, I keep typing `` ` `` instead of `~` in `org-mode` and I would like to remap it so I can make my mistake without noticing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend it, but you can do what you've asked for like so:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)

(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `org-mode' behaviours."
  ;; Buffer-local key translation from "`" to "~".
  (let ((keymap (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (set-keymap-parent keymap key-translation-map)
    (setq-local key-translation-map keymap)
    (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "`") (kbd "~"))))
```

I think what you *actually* want to do is bind <kbd>`</kbd> to insert a `~` character, which covers your requirement without the same side-effects. e.g.:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "org"
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "`") (kbd "~")))
```

The latter will still allow you to type (for instance) <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, while the former will not.

Comment: You've grasped my intention accurately. The second solution works swimmingly, thank you.